# Dados não aparece no phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estou com problemas na hora de enviar os dados passados pelo formulário + php,e aparecer no banco de dados....Quando vou no phpMyadmin só aparece os dados que uma vez eu setei manual,não está sendo dinâmico para exibir no phpMyadmin,Gostaria da ajuda de vocês...estou com a cabeça doendo já...
**Conexao**

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$banco = "cadastro";


//criar conexao
$conn = mysql_connect($servidor,$user,$pass,$banco)or die(mysql_error());

 echo ("enviado com sucesso");


mysql_select_db($banco)or die(mysql_error());
```

**As variáveis php**

```
$Cobranca          = $_POST['Cobranca'];
 $Conducao          = $_POST['Conducao'];
 $conforto          = $_POST['conforto'];
 $Conservacao       = $_POST['Conservacao'];
 $CumprimentoParada = $_POST['CumprimentoParada'];
 $Distancia         = $_POST['Distancia'];
 $email             = $_POST['email'];
 $Entrega           = $_POST['Entrega'];
 $horario           = $_POST['horario'];
 $Itinérario        = $_POST['Itinérario'];
 $Limpeza           = $_POST['Limpeza'];
 $Manutencao        = $_POST['Manutencao'];
 $phone             = $_POST['phone'];
 $tCobrador         = $_POST['tCobrador'];
 $Tratamento        = $_POST['Tratamento'];
 $email             = $_POST['email'];
 $phone             = $_POST['phone'];
 $erro = 0;
```

**Inserindo no banco chamado todas as variáveis**

```
$insereDados = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas(Cobranca,Conducao,conforto,Conservacao,CumprimentoParada)VALUES('$Cobranca','$Conducao','$conforto','$Conservacao')");
```

Comment: acho que eu ja sei o que e mas diz ai qual e a mensagem de erro que esta aparecendo

Comment: outra coisa faca melhor o uso do case sensitive nas suas variaveis

Comment: Tipo,exibe o  - echo ("enviado com sucesso");  mas no phpMyadmin eu clico em select,ou Update ,na parte de SQL no phpMyadmin,exibe o erro #1064 mais especifico quando clico em update

Comment: acho que a resposta abaixo renponde a sua pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro problema que detetei: 
Os parâmetros do seu **mysql_connect** não se encontram corretos. Você tem:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servidor,$user,$pass,$banco);
```

Embora já se encontre **deprecated** a função **mysql_connect** apenas recebe **3** parâmetros de entrada, sendo eles:

Servidor - No seu caso **$servidor**
Utilizador - No seu caso **$user**
Password (**Opcional**) - No seu caso **$pass**

No seu **mysql_select_db** é que você vai selecionar o seu banco de dados e aí fazer uma verificação se existe ou não.

```
mysql_select_db($banco)
if (!$banco){
   echo "Ocorreu um erro";
}
```

Ou pode apenas utilizar o **mysql_error()**.

Por último, na sua query está faltando você chamar a sua **$conn** no final do **INSERT**

***Nota:*** Leia acerca de mysqli. A função mysql encontra-se ultrapassada como disse o Miguel. A utilização desta função poderá criar graves falhas de segurança nos sistemas que possa desenvolver.

Comment: **you have a error in your sql syntax ;check the manual that corresponde to your Mysql server version for the rigth syntax to use near'[value-1],'itinerario'=[value-2] em todas as variaveis erro #1064**   Fiz tudo que vocês pediram pra fazer e exibe a mensagem enviado com sucesso não aparece erro na página,o problema é no banco que não estou visualizando ...

Comment: Pode colocar uma imagem seguida do erro ? Torna-se mais fácil de compreender